# How to return the specific element properties from a jquery collection, with click() event?

Tags: jquery

I've written some code, but the jquery is not optimized, as I'm sure this could be done with one simple function rather than repeating it 5 times...

I just don't understand jquery well enough to figure it out.

https://codepen.io/bensdb/pen/pQGdMG

Basically I would rather have the .click() on all of the .lists elements rather than by id, and then to determine which one it is and act accordingly.

At the moment I am choosing everything individually like this... Any ideas?

```
$("#listy1").click(function() {
    $(".contenty").hide();
    $("#content-item-1").show();
  $(".lists").css("background-color","grey");
  $("#listy1").css("background-color","red");
});

$("#listy2").click(function() {
    $(".contenty").hide();
    $("#content-item-2").show();
   $(".lists").css("background-color","grey");
  $("#listy2").css("background-color","red");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually managed to figure this out for myself with lots of trial and error....

Hopefully it helps someone else:

```
$(".lists").click(function() {
  $(".contenty").hide();
  $(".contenty").eq($(this).index()).show();
  $(".lists").css("background-color","grey");
  $(this).css("background-color","red");
});
```